# is there anyway to validate SMS sent to a number, without using mobile phone? Like, checking for a message on a site similar to mail and validate?

Tags: validation, selenium, mobile, automation, sms

I have a scenario to automate:

1. There's a button to trigger SMS.
2. Clicking on it sends SMS to all users.
3. I need a way to validate that SMS without using mobile phone. Using any site or portal which can be automated using webdriver selenium.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You can do this by using an sms gate.

Comment: @Jerodev -I've explained in summary and also in step by step scenario. what more do you wanna know? can be specific?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similiar use case, but the solution not quite trivial.

First you need a computer which can receive SMS and then there's quite some work to do, so i'll break it down to a minimum.

Normally if people have to make a step like this, they don't trust their SMS provider (which is probably somewhere in africa, with mailboxes all around our planet.

So you'll create a gateway to check if those SMS get sent.

If that's the case, i recommend that you get a serious provider which is able to rout back serviceanswers to your backend, because there's a standardized solution for knowing if the sms delivery has take place.

Here's a link to the definiton on Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EMI_(protocol) , you best follow the sources to understand how SMS is being handled

**NOTE**:
I'm guessing you don't want to try a simcard, but seriously it sounds like you'd want to do something enterpriseapplicationlike without even knowing the basics of your chosen Protocol. If you like supply a valid usecase for your issue, there's allready enough people abusing SMS for their weird purposes